# How does google music continue to play when back button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, google-play, refresh, playback

I noticed that Google Play Music continues to play music even when the back button is pressed. This surely reloads the page? I'm curious as to how the music continues to play during a page reload.

Also, does Music use AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Music captures mouse clicks, calls `preventDefault` on the captured event so the browser never actually handles the event (reloading the page, going to the url), sends an AJAX request for the new content which replaces the old content (while keeping the Flash player in another div, not being touched) then updates the URL using the (fairly) new [History API methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History).

Then, when the back button is pressed, a `popstate` event is triggered instead of the browser navigating to the new link (aren't browsers clever in the 21st century!)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think it still used Flash, I thought they were running on HTML5 now. I didn't realise you could call preventDefault on browser history events; does this bubble?
I can't remember if Google Music uses hasbang or not, but I could never replace URLs without the browser reloading with Angular using HTML5 mode.